# Stopping a script while running though dialogs

Tags: google-sheets, google-apps-script-editor

I am using a script to save data and clear the fields afterwards. Because the fields are being cleared, I want the user to verify (through a popup) that he really wants to do this operation. I have tried to use an alert with `ok_cancel` buttons, but when you cancel, the script continues.

The code that gets the user response:

```
var ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();
var result = ui.alert('Please confirm', 'Are you sure you want to save and clear?',
  ui.ButtonSet.OK_CANCEL);
if (result == ui.Button.OK)
  ui.alert('Data opgeslagen.');
else if (result == ui.Button.CANCEL)
  return;

/* Delete values here */
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have the delete in the wrong place. Try like this:

```
function myFunction() {
var ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();
var result = ui.alert('Please confirm', 'Are you sure you want to save and clear?',
  ui.ButtonSet.OK_CANCEL);
  if (result == ui.Button.OK){
    ui.alert('Data opgeslagen.');
    var s=SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet()
    s.clearContents()}
else if (result == ui.Button.CANCEL)
return;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, i have tried it and it works. Only thing is that i have to copy entire code into the result ok button, because return line gives a code error.